# Arpabet phonetics to substrings of a word, with Python

Tags: python, nltk

The goal of this is that I would like to be able to turn a word into not just its phonemes but also the substrings that correspond to them. For instance, something like:

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
d = cmudict.dict()
...
print foo('perfect', d['perfect']) 
>>> (['p','er','f','e','c','t'], [u'P', u'ER0', u'F', u'EH1', u'K', u'T'])
```

I'm hoping for something part of NLTK or a widely available resource that I can look into, but anything that would solve this would be welcome.

Also, I'd rather whatever solution not have to lookup substrings of 'perfect' in cmudict. Sometimes the substrings will have different pronunciations than the full word.

Bonus:
I realize this may be difficult when multiple phonemes should correspond to a substring (correct me if I'm wrong, not a linguistics person) for instance:

```
foo('ignoble', d['ignoble'])
>>> (['i','g','n','o','b', ['l', 'e'] ], [u'IH0', u'G', u'N', u'OW1', u'B', [u'AH0', u'L']]
```

For the above, should both L and E correspond to both AH0 and L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using syllable grammar sort of worked, for both the string and for the arpabet list.

```
def str_syllables(s):
    k = ['V' if x in list('aeiouy') else 'C' for x in s]
    k = ''.join(k)
    syl_list = []
    while k:
        end = 0
        if(k.startswith('CVCC') or k.startswith('CCCV')):
            end = 4
        elif(k.startswith('CCV') or k.startswith('CVC') or k.startswith('VCC')):
            end = 3
        elif(k.startswith('VC') or k.startswith('CV')):
            end = 2
        elif(k.startswith('V')):
            end = 1
        else:
            print "Syllables couldn't be computed: ", k, s
            return None
        syl_list.append(s[0:end])
        s = s[end:]
        k = k[end:]
    return syl_list

def phoneme_syllables(l):
    arp_vowels = ['AA','AE','AH','AO','AW','AY','EH','ER','EY','IH',
                    'IY','OW','OY','UH','UW']
    pk = ['V' if any(v in x for v in arp_vowels) else 'C' for x in l]
    pk = ''.join(pk)
    syl_list = []
    while pk:
        end = 0
        if(pk.startswith('CVCC') or pk.startswith('CCCV')):
            end = 4
        elif(pk.startswith('CCV') or pk.startswith('CVC') or pk.startswith('VCC')):
            end = 3
        elif(pk.startswith('VC') or pk.startswith('CV')):
            end = 2
        elif(pk.startswith('V')):
            end = 1
        else:
            print "Syllables couldn't be computed: ", pk, syl_list, l
            return None
        syl_list.append(l[0:end])
        l = l[end:]
        pk = pk[end:]
    return syl_list

def str_phonem_match(s, p_list):
    """
    Input: string
    Output:
        [('per', [P, ER0]), ('fect', [F, EH1, K, T])]
    """
    syl_list = str_syllables(s)
    syl_p_list = phoneme_syllables(p_list[0])
    if len(syl_p_list) == len(syl_list):
        return zip(syl_list, syl_p_list)
    print k, s, syl_p_list, syl_list
    return [(None, None)]

print str_phonem_match('perfect', arpabet['perfect'])
```

It gives

```
[('perf', [u'P', u'ER0', u'F']), ('ect', [u'EH1', u'K', u'T'])]
```

I realized for my specific case, I don't need to actually separate by each arpabet phoneme - just syllables are enough.
If anyone has some advice for a more efficient /better solution, let me know!

Edit: Wait no... since I wanted "per" instead of "perf", and sometimes the order will be incorrect (should be recursive, so that I can check whether CVC, CVCC was right or V or VC was right.) 
I'm not sure if I know anything about linguistics or syllables really, not sure about what rules should be in case. But for my specific use case, I think this will work alright.